Issue with creating multiple instances of Prisma client when connecting to Google Cloud SQL in Next.js
Summary
I'm working on a Next.js application, and I'm using the Prisma ORM to interact with a PostgreSQL database. Initially, I was using Prisma with a local PostgreSQL database, and I had a single file (prisma.ts) where I exported the Prisma client instance like this (provided by prisma):
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient()
}

declare const globalThis: {
  prismaGlobal: ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;
} & typeof global;

const prisma = globalThis.prismaGlobal ?? prismaClientSingleton()

export default prisma

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalThis.prismaGlobal = prisma

Now, I want to connect to a Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL database instead of the local one. I'm using the @google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector package, which establishes a secure connection to the Cloud SQL instance using a local proxy.
In a separate file (connector.ts), I have a function that sets up the local proxy and creates a new instance of the Prisma client with the correct datasource URL for the Cloud SQL database (provided by their own docs):
import { resolve } from 'node:path';
import { AuthTypes, Connector, IpAddressTypes } from '@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

export async function connect({
  instanceConnectionName,
  user,
  database,
  password,
}: {
  instanceConnectionName: string;
  user: string;
  database: string;
  password: string;
}) {
  const path = resolve('.s.PGSQL.5432');

  const connector = new Connector();
  await connector.startLocalProxy({
    instanceConnectionName,
    ipType: IpAddressTypes.PUBLIC,
    authType: AuthTypes.IAM,
    listenOptions: { path },
  });
  console.log('Local Proxy started', { connector });

  const datasourceUrl = `postgresql://${user}:${password}@localhost/${database}?host=${process.cwd()}`;
  console.log('datasourceURL created\n');
  const prisma = new PrismaClient({ datasourceUrl });
  console.log('client generated\n');

  return {
    prisma,
    async close() {
      await prisma.$disconnect();
      connector.close();
    },
  };
}

The Problem
The issue I'm facing is that when I try to use this connect function in my prisma.ts file (where I already have the Prisma client instance exported), it seems to be creating a new instance of the Prisma client and the connector every time the prisma.ts file is imported or used. This leads to conflicts and errors because multiple instances of the Prisma client and the local proxy are being created. Especially an Address already in use error because of the file that is created for the local proxy.
Question
How can I properly set up and manage a single instance of the Prisma client when connecting to the Google Cloud SQL database in a Next.js application? I want to avoid creating multiple instances of the Prisma client and the local proxy, while still being able to use the Prisma client throughout my application.
Additional Information

Next.js version: latest
Prisma version: "^5.14.0"
"@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector": "^1.3.0"
"@prisma/adapter-pg": "^5.14.0",
"@prisma/client": "^5.14.0",

I'm using the App Router and Server Components features introduced in Next.js 13.
And this is how I normally use prisma all across my app.
import prisma from '@/app/lib/prisma';
import FundraiserCard from '@/app/components/FundraiserCard';

export default async function Home({
  params: { lang },
}: Readonly<{
  params: { lang: Locale };
}>) {
  const dictionary = await getDictionary(lang);
  const fundraisers = await prisma.fundraiser.findMany({
    include: {
      fundraiser_media_fundraiser_media_fundraiser_idTofundraiser: true,
      donation: true,
    },
  });
  return (
...

Please let me know if you need any additional information or code snippets to better understand the issue.
